# Composer does not install to installer-path

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to make composer install some packages to a given directory using extra/installer-paths

The problem is that the files in the packages are not installed. Only the directories are created.

Eg. wp-content/plugins/johndoe/vendor/{$vendor}/{$name} is created but files are installed in vendor/{$vendor}/{$name}

Thank you in advance for any pointers and advice!

Sample composer.json

```
   {
    "name": "john/doe",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com"
        }
    ],

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:baz/egg-pack.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:johndoe/package.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1",
        "johndoe/package": "1.0.0-beta.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": ["library"],
        "installer-paths": {
            "wp-content/plugins/johndoe/vendor/{$vendor}/{$name}": [
                "baz/egg-pack",
                "myokyawhtun/pdfmerger"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue. For me it always lands to vendor directory directly

Comment: did you specify installers as required dependency in package composer.json?